# Restrict Lambda function URL access to CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudfront

AWS have recently released the Lambda function URLs feature which allows a function to be invoked via a URL.

I would like to allow my function to be invoked via a URL but only via CloudFront.

I don't want people to be able to bypass CloudFront and invoke the function directly.

Is there a way to configure this? I am aware that I can restrict the function URL by setting the auth type to `AWS_IAM` but am not clear on how I then allow CloudFront to call it.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the only option I see is quite similar to [how you would protect an ALB in a way that access is restricted to CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/restrict-access-to-load-balancer.html):

1. Configure CloudFront to add a custom HTTP header to requests that it sends to the <strike>Application Load Balancer</strike> **lambda function URL**.
2. Configure the <strike>Application Load Balancer</strike> **Lambda** to only <strike>forward</strike> **process** requests that contain the custom HTTP header.

My thoughts on approaches that may not work when using lambda function URLs:

- [`IAM` auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html) (since I see no way to sign these requests originating from CloudFront, maybe that will change in the future when lambda function URLs become a first class citizen like S3-origins)
- [restricting access via security groups](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/automatically-update-security-groups-for-amazon-cloudfront-ip-ranges-using-aws-lambda/) (because there are no SGs for lambda func URLs)

Comment: This is the same conclusion I came to. I think the use of headers is currently the only way to do this and it doesn't really achieve what I want which is to prevent spamming of my Lambda function endpoints from resulting in large bills. With the header solution the function will still execute in order to check the header. Hopefully AWS add better support for this in future.

Comment: I added an Authorization header to the CloudFront distribution to send to the Lambda then I validated it at the beginning of the Lambda code. The HTTP basic Authorization header seemed appropriate for this.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed with AWS support that there is currently no way to do this: "[with the] current design of CloudFront, it is not possible for CloudFront to relay IAM authenticated requests to Lambda URL origin.." There is a feature request for this (but they did not provide a timeframe for implementation and release) but hopefully they provide a solution similar to, and as straight forward as, the CloudFront integration with S3 via the Origin Access Identity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this, but it's kind of funny in that it uses an edge lambda to sign the request before allowing it to pass to the lambda URL origin. Here are two links to the solutions:

1. [AWS official solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-an-aws-lambda-function-url-with-amazon-cloudfront-and-lambdaedge/)
2. [Dario's blog post](https://medium.com/@dario_26152/restrict-access-to-lambda-functionurl-to-cloudfront-using-aws-iam-988583834705)

Still, I find it annoying that it's not possible to simply add an origin access identity (OAI) to the CloudFront's lambda URL origin as you can do for the S3 origin. I'd love to hear from someone at AWS as to why they haven't just copy/pasted this solution from S3 to Lambda...

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be undocumented, native support for CloudFront signing of requests to Lambda Function URL origins.  Neither Terraform nor the AWS Console support creating an Origin Access Control with origin type `lambda`, but the AWS CLI will happily create one.  I verified with this OAC CloudFront does sign the requests and that Lambda successfully verifies them.

I wrote instructions in a blog post to implement via the CLI or Terraform:  https://www.micah.soy/posts/lock-down-lambda-function-access-with-cloudfront/

I also opened an issue with the Terraform AWS Provider to add support for this value in the resource schema: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/36660

Answer (score -3):

Here's what I did to make it work on my side :

1. go to the CloudFront page
2. click on create a new distribution
3. In section *Origin domain* you have to paste in your lambda function URL

   [image: Origin domain setting]
4. Make sure to adjust the caching policy depending on what your lambda function consumes

   [image: Caching policy]

You might want to create a dedicated policy in you want the cache key to depend on the *query string*, *the cookies*, etc...
For my use case I created a new policy to take into account the query string

Comment: This is an instruction on how to use lambda function URLs as a CloudFront origin; but this is not an answer to the question how to restrict access to this function URL to CloudFront.